# Cookie cannot be resolved to a type in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, cookies

I am doing a simple project to learn session management in java. I am getting an error `Cookie cannot be resolved to a type` when I write my jsp page:

```
> Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();` shows error.
```

I am using Tomcat v6.0. A few blogs suggested in adding a targeted runtime to resolve this. But I am unable to add.

Please help me resolve this.

Thanks.

Comment: I am sure you must be writing this in a servlet right ?

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: I am using it within my jsp page and calling a servlet.

Answer (score 1):

```
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
```

Add this package in which ever servlet you have used Cookie data type.

Comment: worked for me, but why isn't eclipse suggesting me this ? It works for all other files/functions I import.